# Pass "this.value" to addEventListener Function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I'm developing a Chrome plugin,The situation is like i have few images like this in option page.

```
<img src="some.jpg" class="same" id="231">
<img src="some.jpg" class="same" id="234">
<img src="some.jpg" class="same" id="1324">
<img src="some.jpg" class="same" id="123">
```

I'm doing this to add Eventlistener on "onclick" event on above images

```
 var a = document.getElementsByClassName("same");
  for (var i = 0;i<=a.length;i++)
  {
    a[i].addEventListener('click', test);

  }
```

So,I want when someone will click on any images i wanna pass the "id" (this.id)of the clicked image to any function in this case its test().

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the event handler function `test` you can simply access the ID of the clicked image with `this.id`.

If you mean that you want to invoke the function `test` with the ID of the clicked image, this will work for you:

```
a[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    test(this.id);
});
```

For reference, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener